# Loading QDesigner UI file from Python script using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried to load Ui file from Python script as follow.

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('SomeUi.ui', self)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    sys.ex
```

When I debug and reach to the line `window = Ui()`, I have error as

```
-> window = Ui()
(Pdb) n
TypeError: TypeErro...ndow')),)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: The *SomeUi.ui* file probably has a `QMainWindow` as the top-level widget, but your `Ui` class inherits from `QDialog` - hence the type-error. If you use `class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow)`, the code should work (although the last line should be `app.exec()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile .ui file into .py file by **pyuic** utility, which is part of PyQt.

1. Find the utility somewhere in python dist-packages, for example, on my system (debian linux), it's placed in

   ```
   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/pyuic.py
   ```
2. Run it with python, specifying source .ui file and -o parameter with result py file.

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/
   python3 ./pyuic.py /home/user/my-app/my-file.ui -o /home/user/my-app/my-file.py
   ```
3. You'll get .py file, that would contain something like this:

   ```
   class Ui_MainWindow(object):
       def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
           MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
           MainWindow.resize(555, 470)
           // and so on... lots of lines...
   ```
4. Import this file, and subclass this Ui_MainWindow (the name can be different) by your window class.

Comment: I thought I can call this `SomeUi.ui` file directly.

Comment: If you read the docs (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) carefully, you'll discover, that uic.loadUi RETURNS class, that you should instantiate to use the interface.